# Loading derived types with a subroutine within a module in modern Fortran

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

Goal: use the subroutine `load_things` to load a library of structures of type `su2`.

Running `gfortran simple.f90` produces

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_load_things_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in cc7DuxGQ.o
      (maybe you meant: ___myclass_MOD_load_things_sub)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The main program follows:

```
program simple
  use myClass
  implicit none
  integer :: nThings
  type ( su2 ) :: reflections
      call load_things ( nThings, reflections )
end program simple
```

The module definition is:

```
module myClass
implicit none
type :: su2
    integer :: matrix_obj ( 1 : 2, 1 : 2 )
contains
    private
    procedure, nopass, public :: load_things => load_things_sub
end type su2

private load_things_sub
contains
    subroutine load_things_sub ( nThings, U )
        integer,      intent ( out ) :: nThings
        type ( su2 ), intent ( out ), allocatable :: U ( : )
            nThings = 2
            allocate ( U ( nThings ) )
            U ( 1 ) % matrix_obj = reshape ( [ 0, 1, 1, 0 ], [ 2, 2 ] )
            U ( 2 ) % matrix_obj = reshape ( [ 0, 1, 1, 0 ], [ 2, 2 ] )
    end subroutine load_things_sub

end module myClass
```

The following web pages were studied without success: [Correct use of modules, subroutines and functions in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran),

[Fortran 90 - to transmit values from main subroutine to the functions and other subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476699/fortran-90-to-transmit-values-from-main-subroutine-to-the-functions-and-other?rq=1),

[Fortran: Calling a function in a module from a procedure in another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194534/fortran-calling-a-function-in-a-module-from-a-procedure-in-another-module?rq=1),

[Fortran 90 How to call a function in a subroutine in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633138/fortran-90-how-to-call-a-function-in-a-subroutine-in-a-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Vladimir F comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191677/loading-derived-types-with-a-subroutine-within-a-module-in-modern-fortran#comment52269978_32192176) `load_things` is a binding name of the derived type `reflections`.  It isn't, as the answer says, the name of a subroutine.

As, then, IanH says, you could change your code to

```
call load_things_sub ( nThings, reflections )
```

but you'll also need to make that a public entity of the module.  You're probably wanting to use the type-bound way so that it can remain private (the binding of the type itself being accessible):

```
call reflections%load_things(nThings, reflections)
```

Which brings up another set of points: you can't do the above.

You're using `nopass` for the binding as the dummy argument of the type is an allocatable array: you can't use `pass`.  However, in your main program the dummy argument `reflections` is a non-allocatable scalar: there's a mismatch there so `call load_things_sub(nThings, reflections)` isn't valid.

Further

```
type ( su2 ), allocatable :: reflections(:)
call reflections%load_things ( nThings, reflections )
```

itself isn't valid.  First, for `call reflections%...` `reflections` must be allocated.  Second, with `reflections` an array `nopass` isn't allowed for the binding.

Where does that leave you?  Well, you'll have to fix the allocatability of `reflections`, but the easiest thing to do is possibly to just go along with making `load_things_sub` public and stick with the first path, getting rid of the type-bound procedure.

Comment: Well, you could do something like `type(su2) :: other_object;  call other_object%load_things(nthings, reflections)`  But in the absence of other information from the OP that would seem pointless complexity.  Given the references I suspect they just want to call the procedure directly.

Comment: Agreed on all points, @IanH. I was going to strengthen my last paragraph but I saw your answer was edited to be a much more concise summary of the "don't bother".  Another option is to create a container type, but that again is overly complicated for the scenario presented.

Comment: @francescalus: Your "easiest thing to do" was quite easy. Fatigue had induced programing by permutation; thanks for the solution and the keen analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Your module doesn't have a subroutine named `load_things` - it has a subroutine named `load_things_sub`.  Choose the correct variant of the name, and then correct the name in the other statement appropriately.

Subsequent to this answer being initially submitted, the OP added a private statement to the module that makes the `load_things_sub` inaccessible in scopes using the module.  In the absence of other information that private statement should be deleted.

It makes little sense to reference procedures such as `load_thing_sub` through a binding.  Just reference it as a normal procedure.

Note that many of the listed references are for Fortran 90.  Bindings were introduced with Fortran 2003.

Comment: The line `procedure, nopass, public :: load_things => load_things_sub` should provide the public name `load_things`.

Comment: @dantopa That is a binding name and you have to call it as a type bind procedure `instance%load_things`, otherwise it is invalid.

Comment: @Vladimir: my permutations have been tried. Given this code sample, how specifically should the `call` be amended?

Comment: Without additional information, your current approach, where you have a binding to the procedure, doesn't make sense.  If you are just trying to call a procedure, then just call the procedure.  If the procedure must be referenced through a binding, then you need to explain to us why that is so.