# Passing procedure pointer to derived-type-bound-procedure

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I am trying to pass a procedure pointer to a derived-type-bound-procedure

```
module mymodule
use mystoremodule
    implicit none
    private
    type, abstract, public :: mytype
    contains
        procedure :: parse
    end type mytype
contains

subroutine parse(self,mypointer)
    implicit none

    ! Declaring Part
    class(mytype) :: self
    procedure(storing),pointer, intent(in) :: mypointer 
    integer :: myvalue

    ! Executing Part
    myvalue = 42
    call mypointer(myvalue)

end subroutine parse
end module mymodule
```

where `storing` is defined in another module/ derived type

```
module mystoremodule
    implicit none
    type, public :: storingtype
    integer :: myvalue
    contains
        procedure, public :: storing
    end type storingtype
contains

subroutine storing(self,myvalue)
    ! Declaring part
    class(storingtype) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: myvalue
    ! Executing part
    self%myvalue = myvalue
end subroutine  SetExcitationOrder
end module mystoremodule
```

I call the procedure by

```
call mytypeobject%parse(storingtypeobject%storing)
```

With that i get a compiler error

```
The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.
```

I found out that the error comes from the procedure pointer not passing the dummy argument to the `storing` procedure (i didn't define anything as `nopass`). In all other cases the dummy argument gets passed automatically, why not here? It's not feasible for me to declare the dummy argument, as the object which the procedure uses changes.
Are there any solutions to my problem?

Comment: Can you show a complete program, or at least show all relevant declarations?

Comment: Sorry, not possible as the code is confidential. Are you missing a specific part of the the declarations?

Comment: We can probably assume `type(mytype) mytypeobject` and `type(storingtype) storingtypeobject` but confirming that would be good.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32191677) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not passing there a procedure pointer. `storingtypeobject%storing` is not a procedure pointer, it is a binding to a type-bound procedure, not a pointer of any kind.

I wouldn't actually accept a pointer, but just a procedure argument in `parse`.

Something like:

```
subroutine parse(self,mypointer)
    implicit none

    ! Declaring Part
    class(mytype) :: self
    procedure(storing), intent(in) :: myproc
    integer :: myvalue

    ! Executing Part
    myvalue = 42
    call myproc(myvalue)

end subroutine parse
```

and

```
    call mytypeobject%parse(storing_wrapper)

  contains

    subroutine storring_wrapper(myvalue)
      integer, intent(in) :: myvalue
      call storingtypeobject%storing(myvalue)
    end subroutine
```

I think procedure pointers are mostly useful only if it can be changed somewhere. Not necessarily in `parse` but if you need to set it to some other target in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense that this is not a pointer currently, as i never define it as a pointer in the first place. I will look into that!

Comment: Note: For normal pointers one can now pas a `target` variable into a `pointer, intent(in)`. However I am not aware of similar possibility with procedure pointers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VladimirF you are mistaken. Fortran 2008 allows passing a procedure to a procedure pointer with some restrictions (F2008 12.5.2.9p5). I would like to see an actual test case rather than an incorrect snippet. But it could be that the compiler in question (probably ifort) doesn't support that in the version being used.

Comment: @SteveLionel Even a binding used with a type designator?

Comment: I did some tests and I still think the answer is correct. Only my first comment above is incorrect.

Comment: I did some more research and tests. First, in F2008 you can indeed pass a non-pointer procedure to a dummy procedure pointer argument as long as the dummy has INTENT(IN). Intel Fortran 17 supports this. However, the standard prohibits type-bound procedures from being passed as actual arguments, nor can you pointer-assign to a TBP as a proc-target (which is the rule that ends up prohibiting passing TBPs as arguments.)